# DataGrid with huge number of rows via virtualized collection still slow scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have the current set up for a `DataGrid` in my C# application (WPF, .NET 4.0):

- `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of my own making.  The collection is of `IList<Foo>`, is read-only, and generates the `Foo` object on-the-fly when `this[int index]` is called.
- Columns are generated in code because `Foo` contains an array of objects, and I want a column for each item in that array. All `Foo` objects in the array will have the same number of items in the array. The total number of columns will rarely be more than 5.
- It's possible for the collection to have more than `int.MaxValue` rows, so I've added code in the collection to have `LargeCount` and `LargeOffset` properties that the regular `Count` property is based on, which I can then use to page through the data.

After testing the `DataGrid` with `int.MaxValue` rows, I've found the control to be extremely sluggish when scrolling.  The `DataGrid` is quick to display the top of the data (i.e. row 0 is at the top). However, if I quick-scroll by clicking somewhere in the scrollbar, the `DataGrid` hangs for 10+ seconds before displaying the new rows. The amount of hang time is proportionate to how far down the scrollbar I click.

Scrolling **down** row-by-row (via the scrollbar's down arrow button) from anywhere is fine, however scrolling **up** row-by-row hangs for a split second.

I've set the `DataGrid` to have the following properties in my markup, in an effort to ensure virtualization is working right:

```
ColumnWidth="200"
RowHeight="21"
CanUserResizeRows="False"
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualzing="True"
```

I've lookup a lot online about fixing this but haven't seen anything worthwhile.  For now, I'm going to set collection to have a max `Count` value to something much less than `int.MaxValue`, but I'm hoping someone here can help me get this scrolling working faster so that my users don't have to do so much paging.